# LDAP with Tomcat7

Tags: jsp, tomcat, active-directory

Does this work for anybody, i find guide after guide on the internet and nothing seems to work.

I've added below to my /manager/web.inf

```
  <security-constraint>
     <display-name>your web app display name</display-name>
     <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
       <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
       <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>Users</role-name>
     </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
   <login-config>
     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
     <form-login-config>
       <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
       <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
     </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
   <security-role>
     <description>your role description</description>
     <role-name>Users</role-name>
 </security-role>
```

I get the below error when trying to open the manager app from root:

```
404 Not found

The page you tried to access (/manager/status) does not exist.

The Manager application has been re-structured for Tomcat 7 onwards and some of URLs have changed. All URLs used to access the Manager application should now start with one of the following options:

/manager/html for the HTML GUI
/manager/text for the text interface
/manager/jmxproxy for the JMX proxy
/manager/status for the status pages
Note that the URL for the text interface has changed from "/manager" to "/manager/text".

You probably need to adjust the URL you are using to access the Manager application. However, there is always a chance you have found a bug in the Manager application. If you are sure you have found a bug, and that the bug has not already been reported, please report it to the Apache Tomcat team.
```

404 error???

Below is the only thing relevant i can find in the logs:

```
Mar 18, 2014 10:13:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
FINE: Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp]
```

Comment: What does any of what you added to your manager's web.xml have to do with LDAP? Wait, web.inf or web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question title, I guess you want to setup an LDAP authentication on your Tomcat manager.

You should not modify the manager web app in order to secure the manager. In Java EE, the security constraint is a rule for the application very distinct from the authentication managed by the container.

The appropriate solution is to configure the authentication strategy used by the container, which is a pure tomcat conf. Replace in *conf/server.xml* the default [UserDatabaseRealm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/realm.html#UserDatabase_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm) defined for the engine running the manager with the appropriate authentication strategy, for example a [JNDIRealm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/realm.html#JNDI_Directory_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm) for an LDAP authentication. You there just have to specify the appropriate attributes for your installation. Just note that the default conf refers to a global resource which uses the *conf/tomcat-users.xml* file.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add below to the web.xml

```
        <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>JNDIRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
```